# Giving a UITextField two core data attributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, attributes

Is there a way of giving a uiTextField two core data attributes? I want people to input text into a uiTextField then press a button to change the background to a desired colour. This is then saved in core data and stored in a table view.

Is it possible to have two attributes of core data on one text field?
e.g. a transformable attribute to save the colour and a string attribute to save the text?

Or is there an attribute type which will save both parts of the data?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Man you are so confused!

- A `UITextField` displays **text**. (not "Core Data attributes")
- Information is **displayed** in a table view. (not "stored")
- A **`NSManagedObject`** can have Core Data attributes. (not a "text field")
- A `NSManagedObject` can have a transformable attribute to save the color and **one** string attribute to save some text. (**not** both together)

You can have a list of managed objects that encapsulate the data you want to display (e.g. in a table view). In your case, the data for each object is a color and some text. You can design a controller with a text field and a button as input interfaces to create / edit these managed objects.

Keep the **model** ("store", "retrieve", "save", "attributes") and the **view** ("a text field", "a background", "a table view") separate in your mind.

**Edit**

Since you are still confused: You have to understand the MVC "Model-View-Controller" pattern. Your text field is a **view**. Your core data object is the **model**. Your link the two with a **controller**. The controller can retrieve a core data object with text and color, and fill/style the text field accordingly.

This is very basic stuff. Please read Apple's [documentation on MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Comment: ok thanks, but what I wanted to know was if a text field can have two attributes from the nsmanagedobject linked to it e.g. one attribute to save the text and one to save the background colour

Comment: What does "linked to it" mean? The text field is a **view**. Core data is a **model**. The link between them is the **controller**. The controller can get info from Core Data and style the text field. Clear?